# How to fix the bellow code that is meant to add minutes to timestamp and final value should be also in timestamp as I will do some database queries?

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, unix-timestamp

```
var startDate = 1582530967;

var intervalDate = moment(new Date(startDate)).add(30, 'minutes').toDate().valueOf()

console.log(intervalDate);
```

The above codes makes bug adding 30 minutes makes it

```
Monday, March 16, 2020 5:56:07 AM GMT+02:00
```

Comment: JavaScript uses timestamps in milliseconds, the value you provided is in seconds.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to go from timestamp to a new timestamp, just add the correct number of seconds.

```
var startDate = 1582530967;
var intervalDate = startDate + 30 * 60; // 30 min * 60 sec in a min
```

If working in milliseconds:

```
var startDate = 1582530967000;
var intervalDate = startDate + 30 * 60 * 1000; // 1000 ms in sec
```

Comment: Thank you, been battling with this and searching StackOverflow without winning :)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your `startDate` variable might be in *seconds* when it should be *milliseconds*, and therefore have 3 more digits. Here is your code with slight change to get more accurate start date:

```
var startDate = new Date().valueOf();
var intervalDate = moment(new Date(startDate)).add(30, 'minutes').toDate().valueOf()
```

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/niiyeboah/pen/wvagoev)

The code seems to correctly add 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Would this solve your concern?

Working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-shamir-0yuxq

```
//using momentjs
var moment = require("moment");

//converting timestamp to date
var time = moment.unix(1368457233).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");

//adding minutes to the date
var addingMinutes = moment(time)
  .add(3, "minutes")
  .format("YYYY MM DD");

//converting to timestamp
var afterConversion = moment(addingMinutes).format("X");
```